# Can't mount SMB folders on rooted device

Tags: root-access, networking, mount, kernel

Android 4.3 on a rooted Samsung galaxy note. Astro file manager can work with my network (SMB) folders but the CIFS Manager app says "mount: no such device". (Mount Manager app doesn't seem to support passwords.)

Is this a problem with the kernel? How can I find out?

Comment: you can check if `cifs` module is loaded with this command: `lsmod|grep cifs`. If it gives no output then it is not loaded.

Comment: `lsmod` says "/proc/modules: No such file or directory". Terminal emulator has been granted root. So I don't know...

Comment: This means that kernel is compiled without loadable module support. I do not think you can get this running without flashing a different kernel.